# Throw an error/warning when supplying wrong argument type to C function

Tags: c, function, gcc, types

I have this code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void something(float a);

int main()
{
   uint8_t a = 28;
   
   something(a);

   return 0;
}

void something(float a)
{
   
   printf("%f\n", a);
}
```

I am using a similar function to log variables of different types to a file and I would like to get an error/warning message since I am calling function *something* with a wrong argument type (uint8_t instead of float).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The code is valid because a `uint8_t` can be implicitly converted to a `float` with no loss of value.

Comment: `How can I achieve this?` Why not make `struct something_arg { float a; }` and then require `void something(struct something_arg arg)` ?

Comment: @dbush I get no warning  when using void something (uint8_t a); and passing a float argument (except for a printf warning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old school trick is to change the function to use pointers, since pointers in C have much stricter typing rules than integers and floating point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void something(const float* a);

int main()
{
   uint8_t a = 28;
   
   /* gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors */
   something(&a); // error: passing argument 1 of 'something' from incompatible pointer type
   something(a);  // error: passing argument 1 of 'something' makes pointer from integer without a cast

   return 0;
}

void something(const float* a)
{
   printf("%f\n", *a);
}
```

The modern C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void something_float (float a);

#define something(x) _Generic((x), float: something_float)(x)

int main()
{
   uint8_t a = 28;
   
   something(a); // error: '_Generic' selector of type 'unsigned char' is not compatible with any association

   return 0;
}

void something_float (float a)
{
   printf("%f\n", a);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `_Generic`!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've never came across _Generic and I will definitely look into it!

Comment: @godo It was introduced in C11 and there was some bug fixes to it in C17. I'd recommend using the latest version of gcc or clang for this.